# Azure CosmosDB: get the last month's documents by day

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure CosmosDB with the SQL api and I am trying to create, in my frontend, a graph that represents, in a month, all the documents that have been uploaded each specific day. The graph should be at most a month long. Below I have attached a screenshot of a mock of my idea. After some discussion in the comments I will add the data schema too.

[image: Each day would pretty much show the COUNT(message) of the logs that day]

**Example of the data message** (partition key is */message/deviceId*)

```
{
    "message": {
        "deviceId": "device01",
        "timestamp": "2018-07-25T08:47:16,094",
        "payload": "6c,65,33",
    },
    "id": "ff670801-de08-422c-be0a-fa67e6324bb8",
    "_rid": "75klAPTTTHADAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/75klAA==/colls/75klAPTTTHA=/docs/75klAPTTTHADAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0000bc1d-0000-0000-0000-5c112e5a0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1544629850
}
```

Now my question is: what is the best way to get this type of data? I usually go for the more easy and fast Functions but I think that this kind of approach wouldn't really work since I would need to fetch pretty much all the last month worth of data to get how many times something has been uploaded; it would also cost a lot of time and money to do so.

Is there an alternative way of gathering this sort of data? Would you guys recommend another approach? If so which one? I would like not to add any more services since I am already working on a relatively large project and I'm familiarizing myself with all these services.

**EDIT**: Would it be a bad idea to create some sort of document that kept all the information about the current month, like an Array of days? So the query would run just for the days that are not inside the array.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: Why don't you add a javascript stored procedure for this?  They use less RU's, and guarantees a fast response

Comment: @monstertjie_za - how would a stored procedure help? They are scoped to a single partition, so that solution would only work with single-partition collections. Also, why would a stored procedure use less RU? It still has to execute queries within the stored procedure. Possibly it would save round-trip bandwidth.

Comment: Without having any details on your data model, it's difficult to provide any answer to this. As for "fetching all data" - again, without seeing your data model, it's impossible to know if this is necessary, vs taking advantage of aggregation functions such as `SUM()` and `COUNT()`. As for your idea of storing summary data within a single document, that might work, but you would need to guarantee that you execute whatever update logic you have, for every new document you upload.

Comment: @DavidMakogon What would you classify as data model? I can tell you that my data are simple JSONs stored all in the same database, same collection and obviously same partition that report a `timestamp`, a `deviceId` and a value (think of it as a temperature). These are very simple data structures and I just wanted to know if there was an easier way to get a `COUNT()` for each day instead of having to create a custom function.
By the way I can assure the update logic would work 100% of the times since I would put it inside the function that gets the data from the IoTHub to CosmosDB.

Comment: @Eugenio - I'd suggest editing your question to show a sample document, along with sample summary output, and what you've attempted. Also note: it is not obvious that all data is in the same partition, even with the properties you mentioned in your comment; you haven't shared what your partition key is. Does this imply that you are working with a fixed-partition collection?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I've added a sample document and the partition key. I'm sorry but I do not have an extended knowledge of Azure and how it works so I do not understand what is a fixed-partition collection or whatever but I feel like that is out of the question itself. Anyway, would you recommend one way or another to have a result like the one I asked in the question? I would like to understand the idea behind it, the concept, the actual code I can write myself for sure. Thanks a lot again for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from the CosmosDB engineering team. From your question, I understand that you need counts of documents updated per day in the last month.

You could do this in two ways:

1. Issue a COUNT() query with a _ts filter for the date that you're interested in. This is currently sub-optimal - we are working on serving aggregates much more efficiently, and GROUP BY support as well, but we don't have a fixed date for these features yet. If the number of documents are small enough and your collection does not have a heavy workload, you could still stick with this option.
2. You could setup a change feed pipeline from your source collection, trap all the changes and update a separate metadata document that indicates the number of updates per day, with changes from the feed. Here's a link to working with the change feed processor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed

Comment: Thanks a lot, very precise and direct, appreciate it. I will probably work with the first option since right now our workloads are quite small but if we scale in the future I'll keep an eye on it, thanks again!

Comment: @Krishnan Is there any way in change feed, to identify document is updated or created?